# OpenCV 4.4.0 cvtColor Error, color.simd_helpers.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv

A couple months ago I finished a project which used to work, but now that I changed laptop and updated to latest versions I've found many new errors, which I've corrected, but after getting the program to work, when I use some classes to capture video, i found myself with this problem:

```
Error: OpenCV(4.4.0-pre)
/root/opencv_build/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: 
error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::{anonymous}::
CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int)
[with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<1>;
VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 2, 5>;
cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = cv::impl::<unnamed>::NONE; 
cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

Which I couldn't understand, because I'm also using classes to capture pictures and got those to work again, so I think could be with the videoWriter. I'm sorry for the strange portions of code, but I even tried using the "try-catch" clause to see if I could find which line, but it doesn't send it to me. I also tried many posts with similar errors, but most were just for image, which solved the classes that saved pictures.

```
  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
  #include <opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>
  #include <opencv4/opencv2/videoio.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
```

Some of the Mat declarations and uses.

```
 Mat frame = Mat(880, 660, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0)), fgMask0 (880, 660, 
 CV_8UC1, 
 Scalar(0,0,0));
 Mat fgMask0 (880, 660, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0,0,0)), threraton0 (880, 660, 
 CV_8UC1, Scalar(0,0,0));
 Mat aroi12[orobj], acir12[orobj];
 VideoWriter test(direc0 + "Resultados F1.mp4", 
 VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'), vel0, 
             Size(frame.cols, frame.rows), true);

 for (int k = 0; k < orobj; k++){
 aroi12[k] = Mat(880, 660, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0,0,0));
 acir12[k] = Mat(880, 660, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0,0,0));
 }
 ...
 Mat grey2(880, 660, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0,0,0));
 cvtColor(frame,grey2,COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);

 Mat testRegionA = Mat::zeros(grey2.size(), CV_8UC3);
 Mat myResultA;

 cvtColor(testRegionA,testRegionA,CV_RGB2GRAY,0);
 bitwise_and(fgMask0, testRegionA, myResultA);

 ...

 bitwise_and(fgMask0, testRegionA, myResultA);

 if (!afbt && !vacio)
                {
                    threraton0 = myResultA;

                }

 ...

 test.write(frame);
```

Answer (score 2):

You specified the **color space conversion code** as `COLOR_RGB2GRAY`. This means your input(`frame`) should be in RGB format and output(`grey2`) will be in gray format.

The problem is you created `frame` input as `CV_8UC1`(8-bit single-channel array). You can create it as `CV_8UC3`(3-channel) to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I actually didn't declare like that the frame, I just copied two Mat objects, copied them and changed the name, I actually had it as a blank declaration, declared it them way you told posted, but still sends me the same error.